# Create dacpac file from C# library project

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have .`net` solution with multiple projects such as `webAPI`, website, C# library class projects for creating DLLs. Similarly one of the .`csproj` project is a class library project we have for maintaining SQL scripts and SP's for git repo. Now I want to create CI/CD pipeline to automate the database project for that we need to create `dacpac` file.
I referring lots of material and blogs to create a CI pipeline for the database. I able to create a build pipeline but problem is that .`csproj` class project can't able to create .`dacpac` file but only create DLL file. So how can I create `dacpac` file from my current situation? Can we convert my class library project into an `SSDT` project? I want to maintain a database project along with my main project solution on git.

Comment: I will recommend you this opensource https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj. from my experience it works as a charm

Comment: also check this blog https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/11/ssdt-dacpac-netcore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj` open source to maintain a csproj project and build a SQL Server Database dacpac easily.

the open source can be found here: https://github.com/rr-wfm/MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj
and nice instructions here in this blog https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/11/ssdt-dacpac-netcore.html

Comment: MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj helpful in CI pipeline? I want create dacpac in CI pipeline.

Comment: sure it is just a csproj.. you can run `dotnet build` and generate the desired dacpac

Comment: If I build through VS or using MSBuild in the azure pipeline I get the same result as DLL file in the bin folder.

Comment: Try to follow the blog I shared, it explain step by step how to do it. I already migrated my project to use this one and it works

Comment: Your answer is applicable to the pure .net core class lib application. I don't whether it will work for .net framework class lib project. I have tried but not succeed.